# TypeError: helloWorld.helloWorld is not a function

Tags: contract-deployment, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

Hi I created pretty simple contract -

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract HelloWorld {
    function helloWorld () public view returns (string memory) {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

When I try to call the `helloWorld()` in my deploy script -

```
module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()

    const helloWorld = await deploy("HelloWorld", {
        from: deployer,
        args: [],
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: network.config.blockConfirmation || 1,
    })
    console.log(`contract deployed at ${helloWorld.address}`)
    await helloWorld.helloWorld()
}
```

It shows an error -

```
TypeError: helloWorld.helloWorld is not a function
```

I am using `hh deploy` to run deploy script present in the deploy folder and the contract is deploying successfully.

Have already installed all the packages and `hardhat-deploy` as well, and `hardhat.config` looks also fine to me, and using same `solidity` version, I cannot find a solution online and same issue arises during writing tests for the contract. Any help would be great with little explanation, Thanks.

Comment: do you get the contract address in the console log?

Comment: yes I do get contract address

Comment: can you try helloWorld.methods.helloWorld().call() ? this is how web3js do it

Comment: not working actually, helloWorld.helloWorld() returns undefined